# the right options to traverse/download the pages/directories of a subdomain

Tags: download, wget, curl

Let's suppose exist a site with the following directories (subdomain)

```
index.php
|-sub1
   |-index.php
   |-sub1sub1
     |-index.php
     |-other.php
     |-sub1sub1sub1
|-sub2
   |-index.php
   |- ….
|-sub3
   |- ...
```

My question is;

1. How can I display properly locally the site of the sub1 subdomain (`http://domain/sub1`)
2. How can I get just the files and directory which are childs of sub1 (`sub1sub1` and `sub1sub1sub1` for example)

I tried the following options (for wget) but it retrieves also the files and directories which are in `sub2`, `sub3` etc..

```
wget -E -H -k -K -r http://domain/sub1/index.php
```

Comment: [Another discussion][1] addresses aspects of this in some detail.


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/746794/wget-difficulty-excluding-domains-and-directories