# Wget - Difficulty Excluding Domains and Directories

Tags: wget, facebook, twitter

I am using Wget in Windows 7. I believe this restricts me to Wget 1.11.4.

For anyone interested in the details, I have posted [a sample wgetrc file](http://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/an-annotated-wgetrc-file/). This sample is actually the one I am currently using. My Wget command is as follows:

```
wget 2> "I:\Current\Wget\wgeterr.log"
```

I am having problems with the options that are supposed to restrict what gets downloaded. As detailed at the end of wgetrc (above), some forms of those restrictions don't seem to work.

In particular, I think I am correctly indicating, with exclude_domains, that I don't want to include twitter.com in the download, as a folder on the same level as the website I am downloading (i.e., raywoodcockbio.wordpress.com). Yet I am getting twitter.com nonetheless.

The question is, how can I prevent twitter.com (also facebook and other social media site folders) from being included in my download?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the parameter [**`exclude_directories`**](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-exclude-directories) or `-X` of *wget*. The **`-X`** option specify is a list of directories excluded from the download. E.g. if you do not want *Wget* to download things from `/foo-bar` directory, specify `-X /foo-bar` on the command line.

Comment: For some reason, that fails to prevent the creation of twitter.com and www.facebook.com, regardless of whether I specify exclusion of e.g., twitter.com or /twitter.com. The twitter.com folder is created at the top level, i.e., at the same directory level as the desired download folder. It also fails if I specify twitter.com or /twitter.com with exclude_directories in wgetrc.